# Getting a Symbian Code-Signing Certificate as a Single Developer?

Tags: symbian, code-signing

I'd like to contribute to [Loadstone](http://www.loadstone-gps.com) I can get the code to compile but self signing does not provide the necessary capabilities to install and run the code. All the sites for "free" Development certificates appear to be boarderline if not outright illegal. Since I'm not a company is there a way to get a development certificate I can use, or am I out of luck?

Comment: I'm blind and a screen reader user. With the current way the site is coded I have no way of telling what I have and haven't accepted. See the following link for a discussion of this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18097/non-visual-way-to-see-if-a-question-you-asked-has-an-accepted-answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, at the moment there is no way to get a publisher ID as an individual. This will change, but it might take a few months.

At the moment the only way to sign applications without a publisher ID is [Open Signed Online](https://www.symbiansigned.com/app/page/public/openSignedOnline.do).

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer. I tried open signed but it doesn't provide all the required capabilities.

Comment: So which capabilities do you need? The ones that are not available for Open Signed Online are also not available for Express Signed.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is specifically for contributing for Loadstone you could ask the folks that run that project to create a developer certificate that includes your IMEI with their publisher ID (funded by RNIB according to their website) via Open Signed Offline.  This would be a lot easier for you (or anyone really) than trying to use Open Signed Online for development work.

Comment: Tried that but apparently there having issues with getting there publisher ID renewed. Thanks for the suggestion though.